# How to use a Objective C library in a VC++/C++ project?

Tags: c++, objective-c, visual-c++

I need to use a static objective C library(*.a) in my VC++ project. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: By VC++ project you mean you are using visual studio on a windows platform ? If yes, you cannot use .a files as static libraries for windows (the code was compiled with different compiler for different platform).

Comment: Yes I meant visual studio and thanks for sharing the information.